Does a HOSTS file block a url even if it's called from inside a web page?
I edited the hosts file to include:

127.0.0.1 example.com            # just an example of course

I then used Firefox to go to a site that hosts ads from example.com and I still saw those ads, and using developer tools (F12) I see that it's still loading the ads from there.
Does this mean that I misunderstood what the hosts file does (because I expected the ads not to be loaded)?

Hosts defines the IP address of a domain. If you defined that domain as 127.0.0.1 you would effectively block that domain.  If you still saw ads after modifying the hosts file, then you didn't do something correct.  Modifying the hosts file is a horrible way to block ads by the way. So an ad called from within a website should have been blocked.  An ad embedded in a video like YouTube wants to do would not be blocked.

@Ramhound Thanks. So it seems like I have to find out what I did wrong. Or perhaps it was the cache somewhere that still kept the old (real) IP.

are you specifying the full domain like "www.example.com" or "ads.example.com"? I don't believe host file lookup will use a parent domain when looking for "child.parent.com". I've long heard that Chrome may ignore some host DNS configuration if it doesn't like it, but i have used host files for site testing before and it seems to work, at least for simple cases. Perhaps a Pihole server is a better bet.

The hosts file may be respected or ignored by the operating system, which you left out of the question. Please include it. As an example, Microsoft Windows selectively ignores certain IP addresses and domains in hosts: https://petri.com/windows-10-ignoring-hosts-file-specific-name-resolution/

@FrankThomas Your comment about the hosts file not checking child domains turned out to be the problem. I thought example.com would include sub.example.com. Turns out it doesn't. Thanks!
